# A practical way to create, copy and paste LaTeX-generated equations in png format with transparent background?

Tags: overleaf, standalone, png, copy-paste, online

In order of priority:

1. Online (I use Overleaf on a daily basis, Idk if it can help) (latex2png website seemed perfect at first but many packages are missing [e.g. I can't use the \mathscr{} command])
2. On an Android smartphone (with buttons for every symbol, typing backslashes on a phone is hell on Earth)
3. Locally on my computers (which is the option I like the less because I have to be using one of my computers)

After some research I found that the standalone documentclass was promising but so far I only managed to make it produce PDFs (or html files but is that even worth mentioning)...

Last note: if there really is no way to do that, I could cope with a white background.

Comment: you can use standalone to get pdf, then convert to png, standalone class has a convert option to make it seem like a single step

Comment: If the purpose is to create a printed book (on paper): Some printing services discourage images with transparency, and discourage image/image or image/text overlay.

Comment: Do they make keyboars for adroids?  And maybe a larger screen?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the equation you want using `standalone` document class

This is an example

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\begin{alignedat}{2}
    ax + by &= c
    \\
    px + qy &= r
\end{alignedat}$
    
\end{document}
```

2. Import the `pdf` file to a graphic design software (e.g., CorelDesigner 2021.5), then export it as `png`

[image]

3. Verify you set high quality settings

[image]

The result is thus an image of your equation with transparent background

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the title (maybe I did not make myself clear enough) my whole goal is not to have to download/save any file: I want to write, compile if necessary, and then directly copy and paste as png. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for TeXstudio editor

1. Install ImageMagick [https://imagemagick.org](https://imagemagick.org/)
2. In your LaTeX editor, define custom command to execute conversion of your file. Give this command the name `convertopng`

[image]

The command is

```
magick.exe -density 2400 %.pdf -quality 100 %.png
```

3. When you compile your file, request that ImageMagick convert it to `png` with your LaTeX editor

[image]

4. To get your LaTeX editor to compile and convert to `png` with one click, add another custom command. Give this command the name `pdftopng`

[image]

The command is

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///convertopng | txs:///view-pdf
```